# Taking 3 photos with StartActivityForResults

Tags: android, android-camera, startactivityforresult

I would appreciate some help, I want to take three photos under the same Intent with startActivityForResults() within a loop, and getting back onActivityResult () which prints those three photos in three imageviews, with MarshMallow, and its specific permissions (I think this is not the issue and it should be solved in my code),

The issue is that the application takes those three pictures, and makes the ArrayList or URIs, but it does not arrive to actually printing those three photos in the three imageviews,

Here is my code, thanks in advance,

```
-----------------
MainActivity.java
-----------------

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //private int numFotos = 1;
    //private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ArrayList <Uri> uriFiles;
    private ImageView imageView1, imageView2,imageView3;
    private Button button_takePics;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        button_takePics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Butt_tiraFotos);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_3);



        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            button_takePics.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
                     }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                button_takePics.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }


    public void takePictures(View view){

        uriFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);




        for (int i=1; i<4; i++){

            uriFiles.add(Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriFiles);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

    }


    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir=null;
        File formattedFile = null;


        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("CameraDemo", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        formattedFile= new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return formattedFile;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                uriFiles = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);


                // AQUI EMPIEZA EL PROBLEMA  ////////

                imageView1.setImageURI(uriFiles.get(0));
                imageView2.setImageURI(uriFiles.get(1));
                imageView3.setImageURI(uriFiles.get(2));


            }

        }
    }


    }


-------------------
activity_main.xml
-------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.faustocheca.photochooseshare.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Tira, escoge y comparte Fotos" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Tira 3 Fotos"
        android:id="@+id/Butt_tiraFotos"
        android:onClick="takePictures"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#feafea"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#feafea"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="#feafea"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Comparte"
        android:id="@+id/Butt_comparte"
        />




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have never seen that a Camera app will take three pictures and then return an triggers onActivityResult. Is this indeed happening? Can you take three pictures before the Camera closes?

Comment: `the application takes those three pictures`  ?? Which application? The Camera app will take a picture. Not your app. What do you mean?

Comment: `not arrive to actually printing those three photos in the three imageviews`. Please do not that call printing. One loads an image in an image view. What do you mean with 'does not arrive to' ? Is onActivityResult trigered or not? Explain much better what happens and what not happens.

Comment: `// AQUI EMPIEZA EL PROBLEMA  ////////`. But what is the problem? Do you indeed get three uris in that intent?

Comment: When I debug onActivityResult, I do get three uriFiles (Uris)  but looking more closely now I see...  the three are the same ¡¡¡  hummmmm

Answer (score 1):

This will not work; a single startActivityForResult will result in a single call to onActivityResult.

There's no contract in the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE documentation or elsewhere in the system that says that you can issue it multiple times and get one result with 3 URIs.

You'll have to loop it so that you fire one intent, wait for the result, fire the second intent, wait for the result, etc.

You *may* be able to fire the 3 intents in a loop like this, but I'm not sure I'd trust that the responding camera application would actually be invoked 3 times.  But even so, you'll receive 3 separate onActivityResult calls, if that works.

Comment: Thanks for answer but what you suggest is similar to doing it for one picture and repeating the process three time, which is what most examples around do, but that is not intended. What I would like is to tell the app to do it X times as in my code, let us say three times for example, and then puting the result Uris in an ArrayList to manage all the printing..

Comment: @FaustoCheca: "What I would like is to tell the app to do it X times as in my code" -- that is not possible via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You are welcome to find some specific camera app that has its own API that offers this, then force all your users to install that camera app. Or, use the camera APIs directly.